# Lexical versus dynamic scope, let form, declare form

Tags: common-lisp

Dynamic versus lexical scope.

```
; One expects lexical scope.    
(let (( a '(a))) 
  (defun func1 (x)
    (setq a (cons x (cons (func2 x) a))))
  (defun func2 (y) 
    (setq a (cons y a))))

(func1 'b)
=> (B (B A) B A)
```

Doing it lexically, one would expect
the following.

1. Substitute `(a)` for the `a` in `func2`.
2. `func2` is called with `x`, i.e. the value `b`.
3. `func2` also attaches the value of `a` with `(a)`.
4. So the `(cons y a)` evaluates to `(b a)`.
5. `(setq a (cons y a)))` is `(b a)`.
6. So `func1` will cons `(b a)` with `(a)`.
7. `x` is then consed `(b (b a) a))`.
8. End result `(b (b a) a)`?  Is this a contradiction?

Let us try a dynamical version.
    ; dynamic scope

```
(defparameter a '(a)) 

(defun func1 (x)
  (setq a (cons x (cons (func2 x) a))))

(defun func2 (y) 
  (setq a (cons y a)))

(func1 'b)
=>(B (B A) B A)
```

This works as is to be expected but is the same as in lexical scope?

But the following is not accepted at all.

```
; This won't work.
(let (( a '(a))) 
  (defun func1 (x)
    (declare (special a)) 
    (setq a (cons x (cons (func2 x) a))))
  (defun func2 (y) 
    (declare (special a))
    (setq a (cons y a))))

(func1 'b)
Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable `A'.
```

What is going on?

Comment: There is a side-effect in `func2` that changes the binding of `a`. That's why you get `(b a)` when you evaluate `a` in `func1`

Comment: The `a` declared as special you reference in the last example refers to the dynamically scoped `a` and has nothing to do with the lexical binding around the `defun`. The reason you have *unbound variable* is because apparently at this point you did not yet have `(defparameter a 'something)`.

Comment: So step 6 is wrong. `a` has been changed already. Note also that this is very poor code: global functions changing a shared lexical variable is a recipe for debugging disaster.

Comment: Yes, step 6 is wrong as [Common Lisp requires left-to-right order of evaluation of arguments in function forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababc.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the keen eyes.  This example is from a 31 years old printed Lisp textbook straight out of the chapter "dynamic versus lexical scoping".  The explanation comes also straight out of that book.  I guess that the lexical scoping was not checked, because the authors explicitly warn the readers that lexical scoping was not done in Lisp.  I am happy that this is solved. I stared some time on it, without understanding what was really going on.  It seemed to be an odd contradiction.